# How to display individual rating summary?

Tags: magento-1.6, review

I am using Review module to allow customers to set rating to product.
I have three different ratings.
Then i call `->getRatingSummary()` from
`code\core\Mage\Review\Model\Review\Summary.php`
to get summary rating from all votes.

What should i do to get summary rating for each my rating? (I have three records in "select * from  rating")

I suppose the data for this is stored in

```
select * from  rating_option_vote_aggregated
```

in the column [percent].

What method should i call to get summary rating for my each rating?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get Rating Array Try the Below Code.

```
$prod=Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load('your Prodouct Id');
$productId = $prod->getId();
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
            ->getResourceCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addEntityFilter('product', $productId)
            ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
            ->setDateOrder()
            ->addRateVotes();


    if (count($reviews) > 0) {
        foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
            foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) {
                $ratings[] = $vote->getPercent();
            }
        }
    print_r($ratings);
}
```